We are trying to implement Single Login Session and Kick out existing session if User try to login from different device
We are trying to implement Single Login Session and Kick out existing session if  User try to login from  different device.
We have referred this blog and implemented the code
https://safe.menlosecurity.com/https://edwenkerk.hashnode.dev/sitecore-10-single-login-session-and-kick-idle-user
but this code is working fine in our local dev environment ,and QA also working fine as expected but user cannot able to logout from Identity Server in QA-CM.
Below is the line of code implemented
using System;
using Sitecore.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn;
using Sitecore.Web.Authentication;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Sitecore.SitecoreExtensions.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines
{
    public class ValidateSingleSession : SignedInProcessor
    {
        protected BaseTicketManager TicketManager { get; }
        public ValidateSingleSession(BaseTicketManager ticketManager)
        {
            this.TicketManager = ticketManager;
        }
        public override void Process(SignedInArgs args)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(args.Site.Name, "shell", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                return;

            var validateSingleSession = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("Security.ValidateSingleSession");
            if (!bool.Parse(validateSingleSession))
                return;

            List<DomainAccessGuard.Session> userSessionList = DomainAccessGuard.Sessions;

            if (userSessionList != null && userSessionList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DomainAccessGuard.Session userSession in userSessionList.ToArray())
                {
                    if (args.User.UserName == userSession.UserName)
                    {
                        DomainAccessGuard.Kick(userSession.SessionID);
                        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Audit($"Concurrent sessions detected: User {userSession.UserName} is kicked out ", this);
                    }
                }

            }

            //remove ticket 
            var ticketIds = this.TicketManager.GetTicketIDs();
            if (ticketIds != null && ticketIds.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var ticketID in ticketIds)
                {
                    var ticket = this.TicketManager.GetTicket(ticketID);
                    if (args.User.UserName == ticket.UserName)
                    {
                        this.TicketManager.RemoveTicket(ticketID);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}

//Pipelines
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
                <processor  patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CreateTicket, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']"
                    type="Sitecore.SitecoreExtensions.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.ValidateSingleSession, Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" resolve="true"/>
            </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        </pipelines>
        <settings>
            <setting name="Security.ValidateSingleSession" value="true" />
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>


If it works fine in local and QA, but doesn't work on QA CM, you need to tell us what is the difference between those environments. The code is not a problem. Environment is.

Hi ,it’s working in local but in QA is same user try to login into another browser/device it got automatically logged out from first browser/device but not logged out of QA CM identity server .

For the Concurrent Login,we included AuthenticationManager.Logout() in the code and deployed in QA but there is a time delay in SI logout,it is taking additional time to logout.
and Client is not comfortable with the current visible delay in the logout process.
could you pls suggest what else we are missing to fix this issue.

Additional information,we also implemented the default session timeout to 20 mins.
we referred this blog
/https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2023/07/02/session-time-out-in-sitecore-managing-user-logout-and-expiration/
where we updtaed the CookieLifetime to "0.00:02" and 1200 .
and added a pathch file to implement this session timeout.
00:20:00
false
